# How to move view forwards / backwards

Tags: 3d-view, camera, navigation

I'm very new to Blender, and am struggling to even move the view / camera

I can rotate, pan up/down and left/right, zoom in/out... but I can't actually move forward / backward?

Is the only way to move forward / backward simply by zooming in/out? would this not really mess things up in terms of depth of field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most convenient way to move the camera imho is to activate the *Camera from View* option in the *N panel > View*. Now when you'll be in camera view it will work as if you were in viewport navigation:

[image]

Also it's convenient to have the *Orbit Around Selection* option enabled in the *Edit > Preferences > Orbit & Pan*.